# SQL Server error Procedure or function 'PerformKeywordSearch' expects parameter '@SearchString', which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

This issue is driving me mad. I have a snippet of code that submits a value to a stored procedure:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC PerformKeywordSearch", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { Value = submittedString, DbType = DbType.String, ParameterName = "@SearchString" });

                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    matches.Add(
                        int.Parse(dr["JobID"].ToString()),
                        float.Parse(dr["RANK"].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
```

In SQL Server profiler I can see that it is submitting this to the database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC PerformKeywordSearch',N'@SearchString nvarchar(26)',@SearchString=N'( software AND developer )'
```

I always get the error:

Procedure or function 'PerformKeywordSearch' expects parameter '@SearchString', which was not supplied.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this, if I re-format it slightly to be:

EXEC PerformKeywordSearch @SearchString=N'( software AND developer )'

Then everything works perfectly. Is this an issue with ADO.NET or do I need some clever formatting to make this work?

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e7366e9-7b16-4ad2-9616-816ccbffdf63/executing-stored-procedure-with-input-parameters-using-spexecutesql?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as below:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "PerformKeywordSearch";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "software AND developer";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
// Return value use reader
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Not return value use
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Reference in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2